# ¿Porque el codigo np.sin(escalar*[vector]) no corre?

Tags: python

este es un codigo para el calculo de una funcion senoidal que permite determinar el comportamiento de las ondas, pero no corre

```
xi = 0.1
W = 0.00981*kN
g = 9.81
k = 1
u0 = 0.05
up0 = 1
u̇ = 1
c = 2*(W/g)*xi*omega_n
omega_n = sqrt(k*g/W)
omega_D = omega_n*sqrt(1-xi**2)
alpha=omega_D*t
t = np.linspace(0,10,int(1E3))
def u1(t):
    return u̇/omega_D*E**(-xi*omega_n*t)*np.asarray(sin(omega_D*t))/(u̇/omega_n)
u_01 = u1(t)
plt.axis([0, 10, -u0, u0])
plt.plot(t,u_01/cm,color = 'red',linewidth =5)
plt.ylabel('Posición [m]')
plt.xlabel('Tiempo [s]')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problemas iniciales:**

*Usando py2*

- Caracter no ASCII `u̇`

*Usando py3*

- `kN`, `omega_n`, `sqrt()`, `t`, `np`, `E`, `sin()` no definidos...
- Líneas `alpha=omega_D*t` y `t = np.linspace(0,10,int(1E3))` al revés?

**Problema principal:**

Una vez solucionados todos estos se puede llegar al error de la función `u1()`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 24, in <module>
    u_01 = u1(t)
  File "a.py", line 22, in u1
    return u̇/omega_D*E**(-xi*omega_n*t)*np.asarray(sin(omega_D*t))/(u̇/omega_n)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Suele ser conveniente separar líneas largas para facilitar el trabajo con éstas:

```
def u1(t):
    A = u̇/omega_D*E**(-xi*omega_n*t)
    B = np.asarray(sin(omega_D*t))
    C = u̇/omega_n
    return A*B/C
```

Ahora el error es más fácil de localizar

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 27, in <module>
    u_01 = u1(t)
  File "a.py", line 23, in u1
    B = np.asarray(sin(omega_D*t))
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Si se expande `B` aún más se puede ver que el producto `omega_D*t` funciona correctamente y que retorna un `numpy.ndarray`. Sin embargo, el error lo provoca `sin()` en caso de estar usando `math.sin()`

**Solución:**
Se debe emplear la función `sin()` que ofrece Numpy: `np.sin()`

**Problemas finales:**

- `plt`, `cm` no definidos

**CÓDIGO DEFINITIVO**

```
from math import sqrt, sin
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
kN = 1
omega_n=1
E = 1
cm = 100

xi = 0.1
W = 0.00981*kN
g = 9.81
k = 1
u0 = 0.05
up0 = 1
u̇ = 1
c = 2*(W/g)*xi*omega_n
omega_n = sqrt(k*g/W)
omega_D = omega_n*sqrt(1-xi**2)

t = np.linspace(0,10,int(1E3))
alpha=omega_D*t

def u1(t):
    A = u̇/omega_D*E**(-xi*omega_n*t)
    B = np.asarray(np.sin(omega_D*t))
    C = u̇/omega_n
    return A*B/C

u_01 = u1(t)
plt.axis([0, 10, -u0, u0])
plt.plot(t,u_01/cm,color = 'red',linewidth =1)
plt.ylabel('Posición [m]')
plt.xlabel('Tiempo [s]')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

PD: para facilitar el análisis suele ser interesante añadir la salida esperada y la salida real, sea incorrecta o error.

Comment: Excelente ejemplo de como depurar un problema.